# Level of security TPM2.0

Tags: encryption, tpm, trusted-boot

How secure is it to seal only to PCRs 0 and PCRs 2-7 with fTPM 2.0? My device does not support Intel  TXT, so I am unable to extend the chain of trust to implement DRTM, and thus cannot use PCRs 17-22.

Are the 7 PCRs that I'm sealing data to enough to perform secure platform attestation, and if not, is there any way that I can increase the level of security given my current position?